# 7ZIP - Command Line Compression | Can Never Keep it Simple

Tags: windows, 7-zip

I've been Googleing for a few hours on how to just compress a file inside a directory and I can't find anything. I found how to just compress a folder in general. Now I wish to know how I can compress a folder in a folder with a file. Current code:

```
7zG.exe a -tzip "test.zip" dontcompressme/compressme/new.txt
pause
```

As you can see above, I don't want to compress the first folder, but only the second and what ever is within that folder. I have the 7zG.exe sitting in the main folder and I have some files that are three folders in, but I don't know how to only compress those. Here is my directory list:

- Folder One (don't compress)

  - Folder Two (don't compress)

    - Folder Three (okay to compress)

      - Document One.txt (okay to compress)
      - Document Two.txt (okay to compress)
      - Index.html (okay to compress)

Does anyone know how I can do this in the most simplest way ever invented by man? Cause whenever I go to a website using Google it goes throw all these methods on how to compress a folder, but not do it the way I wish it to do. It makes me kinda upset cause I can't get a simple and straight forward answer. Thank you if you answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd "Folder One\Folder Two"
7za a -tzip ..\..\test.zip "Folder Three"
popd
```

Comment: Works great, but how would I have PHP exec this command?

Comment: You'd have to tell PHP to change the current directory, then execute the command. [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) looks like a good candidate for the first part.